# Android Gradle Multidex - Can't minimize classes.dex, ALWAYS contains max references

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I have an application that has been using multidexing successfully already, but now I have a framework that needs to wrap itself around the main `classes.dex`, which means it needs to be below the max references limit after wrapping it.

But no matter what Gradle dexOptions I provide, the main `classes.dex` ALWAYS contains the max 65535 references:
[image: dex references]

The Gradle settings I have / have tried:

```
dexOptions { // params tried separately and together
   additionalParameters '--minimal-main-dex --set-max-idx-number=55000'
}

defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
   // Shouldn't be necessary for source code within module
   multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
}
```

With the `multidex-config.txt` keep-file containing ONLY my Application class which is pretty small: `com/package/name/MyApplication.class`

Other info:

- `minSdkVersion 21`
- `targetSdkVersion 26`
- Total dex files:

[image: all dex files]

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** Okay so I've just figured out that for some reason it works with my 'qa' buildType sometimes, but not on my 'debug' buildType, and also only works on 'qa' on my local machine, not on others including our build server. I run a gradle `clean` before every build, so it can't be caching that's the problem.

```
buildTypes {
    debug { // DOESN'T WORK
        testCoverageEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled false
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }

    qa { // DOES WORK, sometimes, on my local machine only
        initWith(debug)
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        zipAlignEnabled false
        testCoverageEnabled false
    }
    release { // ALWAYS WORKS - Probably due to minification by Proguard
        zipAlignEnabled false // To be signed later
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

[image: working qa build]

Still have no idea why that's happening.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: No we never did. We needed it to use an analytics framework, Dynatrace, and we discovered that the newest version of the framework could actually resize and move around the contents of the dex files for us when it's too large. I didn't know it was possible to manipulate the dex files like that, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were other tools out there specifically for doing that.

Comment: I was not able to find a solution either. However, I tried out the new R8 instead of Proguard (I used Proguard in my project), and it optimized the code so much that my project got below the DEX file limit. (for my project: Proguard: 93505 methods, R8: 61182 methods). Using R8 you might not need to limit the dex size anymore if you get below the limit as well.

Answer (score -1):

Add following dependency in your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
        ...
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

and also update dexOptions with following code

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Comment: These are unrelated unfortunately. javaMaxHeapSize doesn't affect the output files, and adding multidex as a dependency is only used for minSdk < 21, but also would not affect the output size. If this was required it would fail to multidex at all without it.